# Does celestial body locations reported by PyEphem report apparent or actual positions?

Tags: physics, pyephem

I've been using PyEphem for a couple of things, and I was wondering if the location of celestial bodies are reported as actual or apparent positions. That is to say, does the locations factor in the time delay for information to reach us?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It corrects for light travel time — here's the code where it does so, in case you want to check its technique:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/6849cc42dbb52284f9365655ba84cac5497de1f1/libastro-3.7.7/circum.c#L336